# Nested <li> event only on certain number deep of hierarchy

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Let's say I have some HTML like so:

```
<ul>
    <li> <!-- this -->
        <ul>
            <li></li> <!-- this -->
            <li></li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li></li> <!-- this -->
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <ul>
                            <li></li> <!-- NOT this -->
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I limit a DOM selector so that only the first, second, and third level `<li>` elements are included in, say, a jQuery function?

jQuery might look something like:

```
$('li li li').click(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

(Except that doesn't work!)

Comment: why not give them ID's and call them like so ? like id="level-one", id="level-two", id="level-three"

Comment: @LJ-C that would be ideal but this is an example of a larger problem where I can't use ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the first three `li:first-child` elements:

```
$("li:first-child:lt(3)");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HVt8M/

Comment: so funny, I used this and it didn't work, but typed it wrong. thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('li').not('li li li li').click(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of handling this is like so:

```
$('li:not(li li li)').click(...
```

Comment: Your right, I think this is way I'm going to need to do it. Thanks remus!

Comment: "Handling the selector inside a single event listener allows you to support older non-css3 selectors as well" But this is jQuery, not CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock you're right.. what was I thinking!? jfcallo I think Jonathan Sampson's answer is the most appropriate, will end up being the most accurate.

Comment: ha ha guys you were right, I didn't put a colon in Jonathans answer. Sorry, will have to use his its the good one (and was first)

Comment: FYI `li:not(li li li)` [is not a valid CSS3 selector](http://jsfiddle.net/qeMVA/) because `:not()` doesn't accept compound selectors (jQuery has its own implementation to handle that). That's why I used `.not()` in my answer, so that the original selector can be handed off to `querySelectorAll` or even `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 0):

can't you put a class to each? then all you have to do is the following:

```
$(".class1, .class2, .class3").click....
```

Comment: I cannot do this, see my comment to LJ-C